# Add all network users to local group for specific hosts in CentOS7

Tags: centos7, pam, sssd

How would I add a network (sssd-ldap) user to a local group?
More specifically, how can I add all network users who log into a system to a local group?

It doesn't look like authconfig has a setting to add pam_group (unlike pam_access) and pam_group isn't there by default. I can edit the various pam files by hand, but if authconfig is run again, this is liable to lead to trouble.

In a sense I'm looking for the inverse of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187197/adding-a-system-user-to-an-ldap-group-with-sssd), though I'm using rfc2703bis schema (not that that should make a difference).

Unlike [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/751675/openldap-sssd-automatically-add-user-to-local-group), I'm looking to add the users to pre-existing local groups, e.g. `libvirt` or `tcpdump`.

I'm aware that I can edit `/etc/group` for each new user, but I'm looking for something more robust. Making sure the pam stack includes pam_group would be less problematic than that.
This is actually what I'm doing already, but having to re-run the ansible play to do this every time a user is added or removed from the directory is a bit much.

Using `group: files [SUCCESS=merge] sss` doesn't seem to be an option yet as it was added in `glibc 2.24`, while CentOS7 uses `glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.8` and I can't find any back port notes for this feature. It's still not an idle option though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `authconfig` calls `pam-auth-update` somewhere in it's code, but if you have added a config in `/usr/lib/pam-configs` and run `authconfig` or `path-auth-update` then it should read the file and inject pam_group at the appropriate location in the `/etc/pam.d/` files. See this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/908065/266525).

Something like the below in /usr/share/pam-config/load-groups should work.

```
Name: activate /etc/security/group.conf
Default: yes

Priority: 900
Auth-Type: Primary Auth:
        optional                        pam_group.so
```

The higher the priority number the earlier it is triggered, and pam_group doesn't actually verify the password so contrary to some other examples (like the official Ubuntu one) you can leave that off.

Comment: CentOS7 does not use `pam-auth-update`. That may be a debian, rather than an redhat, family feature.

Answer (score -1):

Just edit `/etc/groups` and add your user there :)

I have my own LDAP user a member of the `mock` group so I can built RPMs in a chroot:

```
$ grep mock /etc/group
mock:x:135:jhrozek
```

The only catch is that you'll need to log out and back in because groups are established on login only.