# Linux: How to optimally configure data partition on multi user system (including LDAP users)?

Tags: permissions, ldap, file-permissions

How to set up a linux computer such that every user having either a local or a LDAP account can use the same data partition.

I would need the following behaviour:

Every user can
 1. create a folder / files
 2. delete only files / folders created by himself
 3. read / execute all files from all users

In the case of users with local accounts I was doing this:

```
sudo mkdir /media/data 
sudo bash -c 'echo /dev/sdb1 /media/data ext4 defaults 0 0 >> /etc/fstab' 
sudo mount -a 
sudo chown :users /media/data
sudo chmod g+rw /media/data
```

which corresponds to

```
# create a folder to mount data partition
# create fstab entry to mount data partition (/dev/sdb1) into that folder
# mount folder
# assign group 'users' to parent folder
# give group read write permissions
```

The only thing left was to manually add every local user to the group users:

```
sudo adduser myUser users
```

Now we added LDAP to the machine. Does anyone know how to keep the desired behaviour but without having to manually assign every LDAP user (too many) to the group users?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pam_group` to add users to the `users` group on demand (dynamically). (Although it's outside the scope of your question, if you were to couple this with `pam_mkhome` to create new users' home directories you could have the system almost self-managing.)

The [PAM subsystem](https://superuser.com/q/451304/332907) (Pluggable Authentication Modules) is responsible for authentication and authorisation. It's wonderfully extensible (and consequently somewhat complex) even to the point of being able to run a shell script to validate someone's login. In this situation we are simply going to add the user group `users` to every login session.

You haven't specified which Linux distribution you're using, so I'm going to give a worked example for Debian. I assume you'll be able to map this to your scenario.

1. Open a root shell and *leave it open until you know this works*.

   Breaking PAM can prevent anyone or anything logging in or even running `su`/`sudo`. You may need this root shell to back out a broken change.
2. Configure `pam_group` by adding this rule to `/etc/security/group.conf`

   ```
   # All services, all ttys, all users, any time
   *; *; *; Al; users
   ```
3. Configure the PAM "auth" stack to use `pam_group`. Edit the file `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and add this line at the end of the file. On Debian I added it after the block for `pam-auth-update`

   ```
   auth  optional  pam_group.so
   ```
4. Test a login (local or LDAP), and check that `id` shows you have `users` in your group list.

   If you do not, then look at the end of `/var/log/auth.log` to see what error message was reported from PAM.

Comment: That sounds very interesting although I never heard of "pam" before. Could you tell me roughly what it's doing or where I could read more about this? I'm using Ubuntu, but maybe your solution works anyway...

Comment: @mcExchange paragraph added, with a reference to [What is PAM](https://superuser.com/q/451304/332907). And yes, it'll work on Ubuntu just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not want to use groups, the only option with regular Linux file permissions is to make it writable by `others` (all users):

```
chown root:root /media/data
chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwxt /media/data
```

This applies the same permissions as for the `/tmp` directory and satisfies 1) and 2).

3) is up to the users, but satisfied with an umask set to `022`, which is the default on most Linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the default behavior of [`/var/tmp`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/what-is-the-difference-between-tmp-and-var-tmp#30504).